# How to configure apache2 on Raspberry pi to serve https?

Tags: raspberry-pi, apache2

I am trying to use a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B as a small web server.  It works fine for unsecured http, both within my home LAN and over the net.  I have obtained a domain name and SSL certificate and key file.  I am testing the server by accessing it within my local network using a browser and the Pi hostname.  Unsecured http works fine, but making an https request results in a delay and then a "host refused to connect" message on the browser.

I have found conflicting instructions on the Web as to which Apache configuration file needs to be edited to include paths to the SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile.
Within /etc/apache2 there are sites-available and sites-enabled subdirectories and more than one *.conf file, but apparently I have not edited the right one.

So, first, which is the correct configuration file to edit with the certificate paths, and second, does Apache produce a log file somewhere that would reveal any error messages produced by errors in the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I found a more complete set of instructions that showed how to add a port 443 virtual host to the default-000.conf file.  It is working now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).